# Show that the closure of a set A is the smallest closed set containing A.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

I need to prove that $\bar A$ (the closure of set A) is the *smallest* closed set containing A. We have already proved that it is a closed set, so now I just need to show that it is the smallest one.

I have written a preliminary proof that I don't think is particularly rigorous, and would be grateful if someone could give me some pointers. We haven't covered anything regarding metric spaces or anything else in topology, so I had trouble understanding other solutions posted on the site.

> Let $A$ be a non-empty set, and $\bar A$ the closure of $A$ (the union of $A$ and all of its limit points). Let $B$ be a closed set with $A \subset B \subset \bar A$ and $B \neq \bar A$.
>
> Since $A \subset B$ and $B \subset \bar A$, $B$ consists of all the elements of $A$ and some (but not all) of its limit points. However, this means that there are sequences contained entirely within $B$ whose limit points are not elements of $B$. Thus, $B$ is not closed, posing a contradiction to the original statement.

Comment: The logic is perfect, only that the answer may be a little too much in words. Learning to write in symbols will help you in the future, but this answer is perfect. Furthermore, the sequences need to be contained entirely in $A$, not $B$ above, for the point to qualify as a limit point, so make that correction.

Comment: An alternative approach: We can equivalently define the closure of A to be the intersection of all closed sets that contain A. Arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed.

Comment: @manofbear yeah but since the OP is using the sequential definition of *closure*, you would have to prove that your definition is equivalent first.

Comment: Agreed, we'd have to show the equivalence first

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward without any of this "accumulation point" nonsense.  The definition of closure necessitates the intersection of ALL possible closed sets containing A. The closure is itself closed (which youve already proven and I accept as a premise), thus the closure is one of the closed sets intersected with to arrive at the closure.  Either by contradiction or otherwise its straightforward to show that no other closed set can exist that could shrink the closure of A.

Comment: Any set B that would shrink the closure when intersected with the closure either cannot be closed or else it wasnt used in definition of closure when the closure was being "calculated".  If B is closed then B intersect the previous closure equals the same closure, and nothing has shrunk.  If B is not closed then its not a closure at all, smaller or otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

I think it is clearer without a contradiction argument:

> Let $B$ be a closed set satisfying $A\subset B$. Let $a$ be a limit point of $A$, so that we can find a sequence $(a_{n})_{n}\subset A$ with $a_{n}\rightarrow a$. Since this sequence is also contained in $B$ and $B$ is closed, it follows that $a \in B$. Because $a$ was an arbitrary limit point, $B$ contains the closure of $A$.

Answer (score 4):

Say $\bar A =  \cap \{ F \supseteq A : F \text{ closed}\}$.
We know $A$ is a closed.
If $x \in \bar A$ then there is sequence $(x_n)$ with ${x_n} \to x$.
Then ${x_n} \in F$ but also $F$ closed set.
So $x = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {x_n} \in F$.
That is $\bar A \subseteq F$.
So $\bar A \subseteq  \cap \{ F \supseteq A:F \text{ closed}\}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof is quite correct. Maybe one suggestion would be to make it clear immediately that you are going for a contradiction.

> ... <strike>Let</strike> **Suppose that there is some closed set be** $B$ <strike>be a closed set with</strike> **such that** $A \subset B \subset \bar A$ and $B \neq \bar A$. ...

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a limit point of $A$ and $A\subset B$, where $B$ is closed, then $x$ is a limit point of $B.$ Since $B$ is closed $x\in B$. This means that the closure of a set $A$ is the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline{A}$ be the closure of a set $A\ne\emptyset$. Suppose $\overline{A}$ is not the smallest closed set containing $A$. Then, $\exists$ some closed set, $B$ such that
$$A\subseteq B\subset \overline{A}.$$
Since $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subset\overline{A},~B$ consists of all the elements of $A$ and some (but not all) of its limit points. (If it contained all its limit points, then $B\supseteq \overline{A}$, contradicting our assumption.) There exists a limit point, $x$ of $A$ not in $B$. Since $x$ is a limit point of $A$ and $A\subseteq B$, we have
$$\forall\epsilon>0~\exists y\ne x~\backepsilon y\in A\cap B(x,\epsilon)\Rightarrow\forall\epsilon>0~\exists y\ne x~\backepsilon y\in B\cap B(x,\epsilon)$$
i.e., $x$ is also a limit point of $B$. $B$ is a closed set and hence, contains all its limit points. We get that
$$x\in B,\mathrm{~~which~is~a~contradiction.}$$
Therefore, our assumption is wrong and $\nexists$ a closed set $B$ such that
$$A\subseteq B\subset \overline{A}.$$
$\therefore\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.